# How to determine the sound level of computer speakers without external tools?

Tags: speakers

Is this feasible with some sound program? Sadly, I don't possess the manual or written information.

I agonise over http://www.mnn.com/green-tech/gadgets-electronics/stories/are-headphones-bad-for-your-hearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will depend on your speakers/headphones. A computer speaker system will most likely have an amplifier inside it to boost the volume from headphone up to speaker. An online datasheet will likely tell you their maximum volume. If you want an exact figure, you could just put a microphone in front of the speaker and have that monitored by the PC, but as every sound system is different your OS will never be able to tell you the exact dB of the speakers just from its own output.